# Code works on localhost, but not on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been working on some code and tested it on localhost, code is work on local server but when i Upload it to my server it doesn't work.

Index.php

```
<form action="" method="post" id="teachome">
   <label>
      Category</label**strong text**>
      <select id="listt" type="text" name="nam"  style="width:188px;" required>
         <?php
            $data1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin_cat");
            echo "<option value=>--select--</option>";
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)){?>
         <option value="<?php echo $rows['cat']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['cat']; ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
      </select>
   <label>Class</label>
   <select id="cat" type="text" name="cls"  style="width:188px;" required>
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
   </select>
</form>

<!--Ajax -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#listt").change(function() {
            var data = $("#teachome").serialize();
            //alert(data);
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: 'fetch.php',
                data: data,
                datatype: 'json',

                success: function(data) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#cat').empty();
                    $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
                        $("#cat").append("<option>" + value.class + "</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Fetch.php

```
<?php
$cat=$_POST['nam'];
$sql= mysqli_query($con,"select * from admin_class where category='$cat'")or die(mysqli_error());
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Internal Error 500 is occurred in Response on live server.

Comment: What's the error log saying?

Comment: Also press F12 and look at the console. Also note that if your server is HTTPS, you need to change `http://ajax.googleapis` to https too

Comment: did you include db connection file?

Comment: Console:- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)